# HTML5 music player external play button

Tags: javascript, html, autoplay

I'm building a single page parallax site. The first part of the page is a logo and a text             button that says "Listen Now"

When the listen now button is clicked the page automatically scrolls down to the next section where a HTML5 music play is embedded. Is there a way to make the music automatically start once the "Listen Now" button is clicked?

Here's a link to the page I'm working on. I tried adding the event listener but it doesn't seem to be working.

http://rob.peytongregory.com/

Comment: Whatever code you are using to move the the "next section" should be able to fire the play event at as or after the move ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the standard HTML5 `<audio>` tag, then you can use its methods, such as `.play()` and `.stop()`.

Therefore, just add a listener to your button (if you do not have one already attached to it):

```
document.getElementById('your-button-id').addEventListener('click', document.getElementById('your-audio-id').play);

// or, similar:
document.getElementById('your-button-id').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('your-audio-id').play();
});
```

Comment: http://rob.peytongregory.com/ I added that code but it doesn't seem to be working. Did I do it incorrectly?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you inserted the `<script>` before the `<audio>` element, therefore the script tries to add the listener to your element before it is created, and obviously fails. To make it work you should **put the `<script>` after your `"listen-btn"`**. PLUS: I edited my code: **it's `addEventListener`, not `addListener`**, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have bound a click event for the button, so just select the audio element and call `.play()`.

`document.getElementById('yourAudioElementId').play()`

EDIT:

If you use `href='sectionID'` attribute, you may rewrite it to `href='#' onclick="customHandler('sectionID'); return false;"`

The handler should contain calls that scroll to location by the given hash and play the audio clip. You can pass audio element ID to customHandler as well.